# How do I pass text data between an App Inventor app, and a computer program?

Tags: android, winforms, server

I'm making an app in App Inventor, that I want to be able to send text to a program running on a computer. I thought a good way to achieve this is to make a web server on the Android end, and have the windows app get data from it. How do I actually do this? what component do I need on the App Inventor to achieve this?  I want to use a C# WinForms app, to make things easier. I want to have the server on the Android side because then I can implement some features where you can choose the IP on the Windows side (which for me, is easier). What sort of functions will I need on the Windows app?

Comment: That's going to be hard to do, and it will only work if they're on the same wifi network (cell networks are NATed, you can't run a server.  So are more WLANs).  You're better off using bluetooth or USB

Comment: @Gabe Sechan They are on the same WiFi network. I guess Bluetooth does work, but it uses more power... Can't use USB because there is a bit of a distance between the two devices. Why is it difficult? Does App Inventor not have any function for this sort of thing? If that's the case, I'm alright with switching it over and putting the server on the PC end... Please do let me know if this is possible or not. Thanks!

Comment: Its difficult because you usually have network issues to deal with, (like NATs you can't control on cell networks) and because there's no built in web server code on ANdroid so you need to write it all yourself or find an implementation.  And Android is not really set up to run servers, a lot of things like Doze and Background Execution Limits are server hostile.  You'd be better off running a server on AWS and having both devices talk to it.

Comment: @GabeSechan I would like to keep this project local, and not use something like AWS. Ok, so if I can't make a web server on the Android app, what about making it on the computer side? Surely there's a way to do this? If not, could I use a web socket, for a direct connection? (I'm new to this communication over the network type of stuff, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Provided its the same WLAN and your router was configured properly it would work.   You'd probably want to whitelist the app from Doze and a few other tricks.  A web server *would* work, but its complicated to write one, and finding one that works on Android would be difficult.

Comment: @GabeSechan So what would you recommend for my problem then, a web server on the windows app, or a web socket?

Comment: If you're talking about putting the web server on the windows side everythings a lot easier (plenty of web servers on windows).  Then you just need to set up your router properly and make http calls.  Whether to use a web socket or normal http calls is up to you, you'll need a web socket library (it isn't built into the default android http implementation), but there's plenty of them.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok, thanks for the info!